# Shapley summary plot interpretation doubt?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, r, feature-selection, shap

I have question when interpreting SHAP summary plot. I have attached the sample plot[image: here]

Here, If I am interpreting it correctly, low values of feature 1 are associated with high and negative values for the dependent variable. However, Feature 1 takes negative values as well. So will the low value of feature 1 include negative and high values?

In other words, is it right to say: negative and high values of feature 1 are associated with high and negative values for the dependent variable?

Comment: "are associated with high and negative values for the dependent variable." - incorrect. You associate features with SHAP values, which indicate "impact" or "contribution" of this particular feature value to this particular predicted value. I may be wrong, but I'd describe it: "low values of feature1 pull predictions 200-300 points down from average."